# Singleton javascript appendChild

Tags: javascript, singleton, chat

I want to insert a `DIV` tag in a `DIV` tag;

I have 1 main DIV tag, and i need to insert many DIV tags within the main DIV tag;

I want to develop a `CHAT`, so the newest DIV tag, must the before all the old DIV tags, with the text sent by the players;

I used a `singleton` javascript pattern;

All the new DIV tags, must be inserted in the DIV tag with id `chat_messages`

I tryed to use this `elem[0].appendChild(div);` but it is not working;

It fails to insert the new DIV tag when using `elem[0].appendChild(div);`

Using `elem[0].appendChild(div);` it inserts the DIV tag, but it will always be the last div;

this is how i test the functionality in console: Filcai.outBound('message');

```
<div id="chat" style="padding:10px 10px;background-color:#eeeeee;margin:10px 10px;">
    <div>CHAT</div>
    <div>
        <input id="chat_message" type="text" name="chat_message" />
    </div>
    <div id="chat_messages">
        <div>
            message 2
        </div>
        <div>
            message 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var FilcaiClass = FilcaiClass ? FilcaiClass : function() {

        var f = function()
        {
            if (1 == 1) {
                console.log('1==1');
            }
        };
        function div1(displayTarget, div_id)
        {
            console.log('div1');
        }
        ;
        function createElementScript(src)
        {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = src;
            //console.log("SRC: "+src);
            var header = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
            header[0].appendChild(script);
        }
        ;
        function create_message()
        {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerText = 1;//document.getElementById('chat_message').value;
            var elem = document.getElementById('chat_messages');
            elem[0].appendChild(div);
        }
        ;
        f.prototype = {
            init: function() {
                console.log('init');
            },
            inBound: function(action, data)
            {
                try {
                    if (parseInt(data.code) < 0) {
                        alert('Internal error!');
                        return;
                    }
                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case 'message':
                            console.log('inBound message');
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert('Unknown inBound action: ' + action);
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    alert('Something went wrong, server returned invalid message!');
                }
            }, //end f inBound()
            outBound: function(action)
            {
                try {
                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case 'message':
                            create_message();
                            console.log('outBound message');
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert('Unknown outBound action: ' + action);
                            break;
                    }//end switch
                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert('Something went wrong, couldn\'t prepare data!');
                }


            }//end f outBound()
        }
        return f;
    }();
    var Filcai = new FilcaiClass();
    Filcai.init();
</script>
```

Comment: *"...is not working..."* ***how***? Any time you find yourself writing "not working" in a technical question, backspace over it and say 1) What you expect it to do, 2) What it's doing instead, and 3) Why you think that's wrong.

Comment: true words, 10x for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said *what* about it isn't working, but just skimming through these lines are suspect:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('chat_messages');
elem[0].appendChild(div);
```

Two issues there:

1. `getElementById` returns an *element*, not a list, so no need for the `[0]`.
2. `appendChild` *appends* to the element (adds to the *end* of it). If you want your new div at the top, you need to insert it at the top, which you can do via [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727):

So:

```
elem.insertBefore(div, elem.firstChild);
```

(Don't worry if `elem` is empty to start with, `elem.firstChild` will be `null` and `insertBefore` handles that correctly.)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('chat_messages');
```

returns only one element, you don't have to use `[0]`.

To include a child element at start you may use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) :

```
elem.insertBefore(div, elem.firstChild);
```

Comment: There's no need for the branch. `insertBefore` handles a `null` reference element correctly. There's also no need to construct the full `childNodes` `NodeList`; use `firstChild`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just saw that in your answer (that I'll upvote). Thanks.